# How do I wait until AWS ElasticBeanstalk has finished updating the environment during CI/CD?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm learning about CI/CD and currently trying to deploy an app (webapp) and a server.

In my CircleCI pipeline, I do the following:

`Build WebApp` -> `Build Server` -> `Deploy Server` -> `Deploy WebApp`

For deploying the EB application to the environment I'm using the AWS CLI (I could use EB but I'm exploring the regular CLI).

When I execute:

```
aws elasticbeanstalk update-environment --environment-name my-env \
--version-label my-app-version-2
```

it outputs automatically and continues to the next step.
The issue, I want to be sure that everything in EB finishes before moving to the next step in the pipeline.

I could use a wait function or timer, but, I'd prefer if there's a way to keep the job running until EB finishes instead of returning.

Comment: What pipeline? AWS CodePipeline?

Comment: Hi Marcin! Thanks! No, I'm trying CircleCI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> wait function or timer

Yes, this is what you have to use.

In fact **AWS CLI provides** a built-in waiter for that: [`environment-updated` ([v1](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elasticbeanstalk/wait/environment-updated.html) / [v2](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/elasticbeanstalk/wait/environment-updated.html))].

You don't have to program your own wait function or timer as you can just use the one provided by AWS.

Answer (score 0):

The time that it can take for the environment to update might be short most of the time but still it is unpredictable.

Following is a very fragile solution

```
$ aws elasticbeanstalk update-environment --environment-name my-env \
--version-label my-app-version-2
# waiting for environment to update
$ sleep 20
# test the deployed version by using curl or some other tool
```

Following is a better solution

```
$ aws elasticbeanstalk update-environment --environment-name my-env \
--version-label my-app-version-2
# waiting for environment to update
$ aws elasticbeanstalk wait environment-updated --environment-name my-env \
--version-label my-app-version-2
# test the deployed version by using curl or some other tool
```

More details can be found here [environment-updated](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/elasticbeanstalk/wait/environment-updated.html)